# How do I replace part of a tree with another tree at the specified index?

Tags: tree, scheme, racket

Suppose I have two trees:

- Tree A — `'(+ (* 5 6) (sqrt 3))`:

  [image: GraphViz: digraph mytree { forcelabels=true; node [shape=circle]; "+"->""; "+"->"sqrt"; node [shape=rect]; ""->5; ""->6; "sqrt"->3; "+" [xlabel="0"]; "" [xlabel="1"]; "5" [xlabel="2"]; "6" [xlabel="3"]; "sqrt" [xlabel="4"]; "3" [xlabel="5"]; } dot -Tpng tree.dot -O]
- Tree B — `'(- 4 2)`:

  [image: GraphViz digraph mytree { forcelabels=true; "-" [shape=circle]; node [shape=rect]; "-"->4; "-"->2; } dot -Tpng tree.dot -O]

Goal: replace one of tree A's subtrees with tree B at a specified tree A index position. The index position starts at 0 at the root node and is depth-first. In the figure for tree A above, I have labelled all the nodes with their index to show this.

For example, `(replace-subtree treeA 4 treeB)` replaces the subtree at index 4 in tree A with tree B, resulting in the tree `(+ (* 5 6) (- 4 2))`:

[image: GraphViz: digraph mytree { node [shape=circle]; "+" [xlabel="0"]; "" [xlabel="1"]; "-" [xlabel="4"]; "+"->""; "+"->"-"; node [shape=rect]; "5" [xlabel="2"]; "6" [xlabel="3"]; ""->5; ""->6; "4" [xlabel="5"]; "2" [xlabel="6"]; "-"->4; "-"->2; } dot -Tpng tree.dot -O]

How do I implement `(replace-subtree treeA index treeB)`?

---

This question is somewhat related to my other question: [How do I get a subtree by index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65000785/how-do-i-get-a-subtree-by-index). I had great difficulty in solving it, but I eventually found a workable solution for that problem by using continuation-passing style (CPS). However, this problem here appears to be far more difficult. I am completely at loss as to how I should even begin! Implementations and clues are most welcome. I'd be particularly interested in implementations that do not use `call/cc`.

---

EDIT

I came up with a stopgap implementation while waiting for answers. It relies on `set!`, which I do not prefer.

```
(define (replace-subtree tree index replacement)
  (define counter 0)
  (define replaced #f)  ; Whether or not something has been replaced.

  (define (out-of-bounds-error)
    (error "Index out of bounds" index))

  (define (traverse-tree tree)
    (cond [(null? tree)
           (error "Invalid tree: ()")]
          [(= counter index)
           (set! counter (+ counter 1))
           (set! replaced #t)
           replacement]
          [(pair? tree)
           (set! counter (+ counter 1))
           (cons (car tree)
                 (traverse-children (cdr tree)))]
          [else
           ;; Possible only during the initial call to traverse-tree.
           ;; e.g. (replace-subtree 'not-a-list 9999 '(+ 1 2)) -> error.
           (out-of-bounds-error)]))

  (define (traverse-children children)
    (cond [(null? children) '()]
          [(list? (car children))
           ;; `list?` instead of `pair?` to let `traverse-tree` handle
           ;; invalid tree ().
           ;; `let*` instead of `let` to guarantee traversal of
           ;; first child first. In Scheme, order of evaluation of 
           ;; `let` bindings is unspecified.
           (let* ((first-child (traverse-tree (car children)))
                  (rest-child (traverse-children (cdr children))))
             (cons first-child rest-child))]
          [(= counter index)
           (set! counter (+ counter 1))
           (set! replaced #t)
           (cons replacement
                 (traverse-children (cdr children)))]
          [else
            (set! counter (+ counter 1))
            (cons (car children)
                  (traverse-children (cdr children)))]))

  (let ([result (traverse-tree tree)])
   (if replaced
       result
       (out-of-bounds-error))))
```

Comment: is `(((lambda (a) (lambda (b) (+ a (sqrt b)))) 1) 4)` a tree? isn't its `car` also a tree? why ignore it? I think it shouldn't be ignored.

Comment: @WillNess `'(((lambda (a) (lambda (b) (+ a (sqrt b)))) 1) 4)` is a tree with root node `'((lambda (a) (lambda (b) (+ a (sqrt b)))) 1)` and one child node `4`. In my tree implementation, the `car` of a list is the "content" of a non-terminal node, and the `cdr` of the list contains its children.

Comment: if your new implementation is working correctly, and you want it reviewed, then perhaps post it on CodeReview? (traffic there is pretty low though...). the code in the answer does the right thing AFAIAC, I'd do the same, up to the syntax of course. or we could first run the indexing from the previous question, pairing each node's payload with its index. I think @tfb hints at that in the initial discussion. then, on such indexed tree, the replacing code would go directly to the wanted node, in log time, instead of having to search through the whole tree in linear time as it does.

Comment: the indexing itself is linear of course, i.e. linear in the number of nodes and leaves in the tree. again, this would work only with the dfs indexing, I think, not the bfs one.

Answer (score 2):

This is a harder problem than I expected it to be.  One reason that it's hard is that the things you are calling 'trees' are not actually trees: they're DAGs (directed acyclic graphs) because they can share subtrees.  Simple-mindedly this only happens for leaf nodes: in `(a b b)` the nodes with index 1 and 2 are `eq?`: they're the same object.  But in fact it can happen for any node: given

```
(define not-a-tree
  (let ([subtree '(x y)])
    (list 'root subtree subtree)))
```

The nodes with index 1 and 2 are the same object and are not leaf nodes: this is a DAG, not a tree.

This matters because it derails an obvious approach:

1. find the node with the index you're interested in;
2. walk over the tree constructing new tree until you find this node, using `eq?` on nodes, and then replace it.

You can see that this would fail if I wanted to replace the node with index 2 in `(x y y)`: it would replace the node with index 1 instead.

One approach which is probably then the simplest one is to take these 'trees' and turn them into trees where nodes *do* have identity.  Then do the replacement on *those* trees as above, and then convert them back to the original representation.  This will however possibly lose some structure which matters: the object above will be turned from a DAG to a tree, for instance.  That's unlikely to matter in practice.

So to do this you'd need a function to take the old trees, turn them into new trees with suitable uniqueness, then convert them back.  This is almost certainly the conceptually simplest approach but I was too lazy to write all that code.

So, here's an answer which is *not* that approach.  Instead what this does is to walk over the tree keeping track of the node index as it goes, and building new tree if it needs to.  To do this the thing that walks into a node needs to return two things: a node (which may be a newly-made node, i.e. the replacement, or the original node it was passed), and the new value of the index.  This is done by returning two values from the walker, and there's a fair amount of hair around doing that.

This also doesn't try and use some little subset of Racket: it uses multiple values, including syntax (`let-values`) which makes them less painful to use, and also `for/fold` to do most of the work, including folding multiple values.  So, you'll need to understand those things to see what it does.  (It also probably means it's not suitable for a homework answer.)

One thing worth noting is that the walker cheats a bit: once it's done the replacement then it doesn't even try to compute the index properly: it just knows it's bigger than it cares about and cops out.

First here are abstractions for dealing with trees: note that `make-node` is not quite the same as the `make-node` in the answer to the previous question: it wants a list of children now which is a much more useful signature.

```
(define (make-node value children)
  ;; make a tree node with value and children
  (if (null? children)
      value
      (cons value children)))

(define (node-value node)
  ;; the value of a node
  (cond
    [(cons? node)
     (car node)]
    [else
     node]))

(define (node-children node)
  ;; the children of a node as a list.
  (cond
    [(cons? node)
     (cdr node)]
    [else
     '()]))
```

Now here is the function that does the work.

```
(define (replace-indexed-subtree tree index replacement)
  ;; Replace the subtree of tree with index by replacement.
  ;; If index is greater than the largest index in the tree
  ;; no replacemwnt will happen but this is not an error.
  (define (walk/indexed node idx)
    ;; Walk a node with idx.
    ;; if idx is less than or equal to index it is the index
    ;; of the node.  If it is greater than index then we're not
    ;; keeping count any more (as were no longer walking into the node).
    ;; Return two values: a node and a new index.
    (cond
      [(< idx index)
       ;; I still haven't found what I'm looking for (sorry)
       ;; so walk into the node keeping track of the index.
       ;; This is just a bit fiddly.
       (for/fold ([children '()]
                  [i (+ idx 1)]
                  #:result (values (if (< i index)
                                       node
                                       (make-node (node-value node)
                                                  (reverse children)))
                                   i))
                 ([child (in-list (node-children node))])
         (let-values ([(c j) (walk/indexed child i)])
           (values (cons c children) j)))]
      [(= idx index)
       ;; I have found what I'm looking for: return the replacement
       ;; node and a number greater than index
       (values replacement (+ idx 1))]
      [else
       ;; idx is greater than index: nothing to do
       (values node idx)]))
  ;; Just return the new tree (this is (nth-value 0 ...)).
  (let-values ([(new-tree next-index)
                (walk/indexed tree 0)])
    new-tree))
```

So now

```
> (replace-indexed-subtree '(+ (* 5 6) (sqrt 3)) 4 '(- 4 2))
'(+ (* 5 6) (- 4 2))
> (replace-indexed-subtree '(+ (* 5 6) (sqrt 3)) 0 '(- 4 2))
'(- 4 2)
> (replace-indexed-subtree '(+ (* 5 6) (sqrt 3)) 20 '(- 4 2))
'(+ (* 5 6) (sqrt 3))
```

It's well worth putting a suitable `printf` at the top of `walk/indexed` so you can see what it's doing as it walks the tree.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Please give me a few days to run, tweak, and understand your answer before I upvote/accept it.

Comment: (after having read the first part of your answer) re `eq?` identity, pointer equality never even enters into the mind of a functional programmer. the FP approach is "persistent data structures" rebuilt on the way up after locating the node - by index here just as well. another non-starter is surgical modification of a containing node, which, as your analysis shows, could be shared higher up in the graph/tree, and we'd end up replacing it in more than one place. so whether it actually has structure sharing or not doesn't matter if we treat it as a tree in a purely functional way. :)

Comment: that way only the nodes on the path to the replacement point are affected; any sharing in other parts of the tree will remain intact.

Comment: @WillNess: notions of identity, (whether or not it's pointer identity, which is just implementational) matter independently of whether there are destructive operations (which I was not suggesting in the identity-based one of course).  I have no idea how pure-functional-no-identity people deal with problems where it matters whether two nodes in a graph are the same node, except if they're modelling the real world they're sneaking in identity somehow and if they're not modelling it, well, I lose interest at that point :-)

Comment: where it matters they switch to C or similar.  (this includes Lisp of course, the ultimate assembler). or decide that it doesn't. :)

Comment: so in the end you indeed do that thing, that I thought about too. except, I was expecting `#:result (values (if (< i index) node (make-node (node-value node) (reverse children))) i))`. (not tested. :) )

Comment: also, this is now intimately tied with the enumeration being dfs. for bfs indexing a completely different, and it looks like much more complex, approach seems to be needed. IIANM.

Comment: @WillNess: yes, the reason it took me ages to post the answer is I got interested in how and if I could do some agenda-based controllable-search-order one and decided I couldn't work out how to do that.  I'm sure there is some neat trick which I'm too stupid to see.  For the result thing: I am sure you're and this would save consing but I'm too lazy to test it to check.  Maybe if I come back to it I will (or if you want to check it is right obviously just edit it in).

Comment: @WillNess I have added my stopgap implementation to the question.

Comment: @tfb re bfs ordering, continuing [this line of thought](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65010312/how-do-i-replace-part-of-a-tree-with-another-tree-at-the-specified-index#comment114997695_65010312), having a tree with nodes already labeled with their bfs indices, we could walk down the right spine and thus discover the *depth level* of the desired node for replacement. how to find it, at that depth level,... for now all I see is kind of a binary search-like trial-and-error probing, for the overall log-squared complexity or something. (the initial labeling is of course still linear).